# GetxController onClose not called

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a getx controllers A which has a property of another controller B. But when I delete the controller A, the onClose() of A is called while the onClose of B isn't.

```
// Controller A  
@override
  void onClose() {
    print('close A');
    B.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
```

```
  //Controller B
  @override
  void onClose() {
    print('close B');
    animationController.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
```

until i add this line

```
 @override
  void onClose() {
    B.onClose();
    B.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
```

I'm newly interested in Getx, thanks for viewing this question:)

Answer (score 1):

Is your controller B is being used by any other page/controller? If so, it's the expected behavior.
Also, you shouldn't call lifecycle methods (*onInit*, *onClose*) manually.